# see ON the images vs see IN the images

Tags: prepositions

As non native I struggle with in, on and at. I usually ask Google for help in cases like this, but here Google reports similar number of results for both options, so I'm not sure what is the best and why.

*see ON the images vs see IN the images*

Comment: I can see Fred in the image. I can see some dust on the image.

Comment: But are there any general rules?  "I see **on** this map that Myanmar is being called Burma again." and "I see **from** this chart that RAM prices are dropping."   Seems idiomatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pair of general rules for you:

> When the image ***contains*** something, or is an ***element of it***, the better word to use is ***in***.

- Is that a dog ***in*** the image with Jacob?
- The backgrounds ***in*** these images are really crisp!

> When speaking to something ***not contained*** by the image, or when referring to the ***image itself as an object***, the better word to use is ***on***.

- I used a Sepia filter on the image.
- Shouldn't we put borders on these images?